# CDialog - EndDialog from a MODELESS dialog?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, modal-dialog, modeless

The [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhk0y9cw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (and [others](http://www.flounder.com/kb103788.htm)) "clearly" states:

> ... Because the normal OnOk and OnCancel member functions of a CDialog
>   object would call EndDialog, make sure your modeless dialog box does
>   not call those functions and instead overrides

Since `CDialog::OnOk` effectively calls `CDialog::EndDialog`, and that method looks like:

```
void CDialog::EndDialog(int nResult)
{
    ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd));

    if (m_nFlags & (WF_MODALLOOP|WF_CONTINUEMODAL))
        EndModalLoop(nResult);

    ::EndDialog(m_hWnd, nResult);
}
```

we can also check [the docs for `::EndDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which again "clearly" state:

> Dialog boxes created by the DialogBox, DialogBoxParam,
>   DialogBoxIndirect, and DialogBoxIndirectParam functions must be
>   destroyed using the EndDialog function. An application calls EndDialog
>   from within the dialog box procedure; the function must not be used
>   for any other purpose.

Yet, I have a `CDialog` derived class that has it's default behavior wrt. `OnOK`and *seemingly* everything is working when I use it non-modal / modeless.

That is: 
* When I close the (modeless) dialog, it is closed/removed from view.
* The application doesn't show any memory leaks. (MFC debug build)

So what? Do I need to prevent `EndDialog` and call `DestroyWindow` myself *or not*?

---

Note: I know what the docs and "the web" says. It's just that I haven't yet found *why* I need to do it differently, and this one class should be usable for modeless and modal mode, so not having to do anything different might be handy.

Comment: I suspect you are leaking a window.  This wouldn't appear as a memory leak in your application because windows are maintained by the system.  Check the "USER objects" column in Task Manager to see if the value grows over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66b3y2ab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for `CDialog::OnOK` clearly states

> If you implement the OK button in a modeless dialog box, you must
>   override the OnOK method and call DestroyWindow inside it. Do not call
>   the base-class method, because it calls EndDialog which makes the
>   dialog box invisible but does not destroy it

So you would need to override `CDialog::OnOK` and call `DestroyWindow()` inside -- here's a modified example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt7c0708%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
class CDlg : public CDialog
{
    ...
    BOOL m_bModal;
    ...
}

CDlg::CDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    ...
    m_bModal = FALSE;
    ...
}

INT_PTR CDlg::DoModal()
{   m_bModal = TRUE;
    const INT_PTR rval = CDialog::DoModal();
    m_bModal = FALSE;
    return rval;
}

void CDlg::OnOK() 
{ 
   if (!UpdateData(TRUE)) 
   {
      TRACE(_T("UpdateData failed during dialog termination\n"));
      // The UpdateData routine will set focus to correct item
      return;
   }
   if (m_bModal)
       EndDialog(IDOK);
   else
       DestroyWindow();
}

void CDlg::OnCancel()
{
   if (m_bModal)
       EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
   else
       DestroyWindow();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't check the method docs here. This seems pretty clear now.

Comment: @MartinBa updated code above to handle modal and modeless dialogs

Comment: Are you positive this works? In my original case I stepped through the `CDialog::EndDialog` function and I think I remember these flags also being set on my modeless dialog created with `Create` ... haven't got the code here though to check this atm.

Comment: Sorry, no -- will fire up an example project and get back to you

Comment: couldn't try this out (have some problems with my VisualStudio), but I looked into the MFC sources, it looks like the flags are being set in both cases, there don't seem to be any other flags either -- the easiest fix seems to be to have a member variable `m_bModal` and set it on DoModal; if you have a lot of dialog boxes like this, it would be better to make up your own intermediate base class  derived from CDialog and use this class as the base class for all your dialogs